# I can't get a valid internet connection with MikroTik Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My router is MikroTik RB951G. It has the configuration below:

```
ether1 - port where the ISP cable is plugged in
ether2,3,4 - are the ports where i plug my PC and Switch.
There is a DHCP server on the wlan1 interface.
```

My problem is with the WiFi. I can connect with the WiFi with my smartphone but there is no Internet Connection.

Where might the problem be?

Comment: If there's no DHCP server, how is the phone expected to determine what IP address and nameservers to use?

Comment: I don't really use any mikrotik gear with wifi but I believe there is/should be a bridge between the wifi interface and the LAN. If this is disabled you would have this problem. Thre could be other things though. Post your config (in 'tik terminal: export compact hide-sensitive file=somefilenameyouchose) Export compact will export only the changes from default. hide-sensitive will keep out passwords, etc.) file= will put it in a text file on the router. Make sure to delete this file after you've posted it. You can drag the file from Winbox's Files window to your desktop to copy it out. hth.